# Finding single escaped characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to replace some escaping character in a given text. Here what I've tried.

```
_RE_SPECIAL_CHARS = re.compile(r"(?:[^@\\]|\\.)+@")

text = r"ok@\@.py"
search = re.search(_RE_SPECIAL_CHARS, text)

print(text)

if search:
    print(_RE_SPECIAL_CHARS.sub("<star>", text))

else:
    print('<< NOTHING FOUND ! >>')
```

This prints :

```
ok@\@.py
<star>\@.py
```

What I need to have instead is `ok<star>\@.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookbehind and just match the special character:

```
re.compile(r"(?<=[^@\\]|\\.)@")
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yE4yT4/4)

Or you can capture the part before `@` in group 1 and replace with `\1<star>`

```
re.compile(r"((?:[^@\\]|\\.)+)@")
```

and

```
print(_RE_SPECIAL_CHARS.sub("\1<star>", text))
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yE4yT4/5)

Comment: Thanks. The 1st method does not work for me contrary to the 2nd one. The 1st method gives with Python3 the message : `sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`.